# Jquery to accept both negative and nonnegative values

Tags: jquery

I have tried this. This accepts only integers. I want both negative and non negative.

```
    $(function () {
        $('.spinner').keyup(function () {
            if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of HTML element is  `$('.spinner')` ?

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg Yes it should. He only needs to remove non-digits if it contains non-digits.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got that wrong, which is why I removed my comment.

Comment: In chrome, type="number" happily ignores anything not a number

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested but have you tried something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.spinner').keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.match(/[^0-9-]/g)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');
        }
    });
});
```

By adding the extra '-' in the reg-ex: the first one is to specify a range, the second one the actual char.

You could also refine the whole process and always set the value to : everything that matches:

```
^[-]{0,1}[0-9]+
```

Start of the line by nothing or -
followed by a succession of digits, at least one or more.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for both matching and replacing. Instead of

```
if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
}
```

use

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/([+-]?\d+)/, '$1');
```

I assume you only expect to find one integer in the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep using regular expressions, or if you prefer "pure logic" which for my eyes is more readable you can use such code:

```
$('.spinner').keyup(function (evt) {
    var previousValue = $(this).data("prev") || "";
    var currentValue = this.value;
    var valid = true;
    if (currentValue.length > 0 && currentValue !== "-") {
        //having something we can check:
        var number = Number(currentValue);

        //integer only if not NaN and integer value equals
        valid = (!isNaN(number) && parseInt(number, 10) == number);
    }

    if (valid) {
        $(this).data("prev", currentValue);
    } else {
        //restore last good value:
        this.value = (previousValue.length == 0) ? "" : parseInt(previousValue, 10);
    }
});
```

This will check every time if the value is valid integer and when not valid, restore the previous value which passed the validation.

Note the usage of `Number()` instead of `parseInt()`, that's due to the later allowing things like "5a" which is parsed as 5 while `Number("5a")` will give NaN value.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/8dCaY/).